# Inscription on stein: “Erst prob’s dann lob’s”

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english, proverb

My mother recently made a trip to visit my brother in the Allenbach area and brought back a small stein for me. One side depicts three men and a woman. One of the men is playing a lute (I think) and the other side is a village and church. The inscription is:

> Erst prob’s dann lob’s

Google Translate gave no useful translation.

What does the inscription translate to in English, and what is the context with the images?

Comment: My first idea was that it is short for "Erst probe es, dann lobe es" (First practice it, then praise it) but that doesn't make sense. Maybe it is: "Erst probe es, dann loben sie es" (First practice it, then they will praise it). "Es" refers probably to a piece of music.

Comment: _Probieren_ can also means try in the sense of _sample_ or _taste_.

Comment: There is no check mark for me to accept these two responses, but I think each of these could be correct.  "Taste (or sample) first, then praise" is most likely because it is on a beer stein. "First practice it, then they will praise it" could also be correct in this specific stein because the woman has her hands over her ears.  So maybe he needs to practice first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inscription would be *Erst prob's, dann lob's!* meaning "try it first, then praise it." It seems a [pretty common inscription](http://stein-collectors.org/library/TranslationsIllustrated/E/Erst_probs_dann_lobs/trans.html) for German beersteins.

Answer (score 4):

The inscription should read:

> Erst prob’s, dann lob’s.

It is a saying recommending to first try something (*proben*, *probieren*) before (possibly) appraising it.

Regarding the pictures, I don’t think they are related to the inscription specifically. A web search for the phrase turns up quite a number of steins with varying decorations.

Answer (score -4):

As I can't imagine that there is absolutely no connection between picture and inscription I would, judging by your description of the picture, rather make an educated guess in the direction of courtly love where the Troubadours have to woo for the favor of their sweetheart. And the choice of the mistress is strongly biased and influenced by the skills of their singing and playing.

So in a figurative sense the inscription says: '***First listen carefully, whether one of them proves worthy, then make your choice...***'

I don't think it's related to 'rehearsing' or 'drinking'! But of course one had to see the picture before making a serious guess...

Comment: As a quick google search proves this quote to be rather fequent not only on beer steins (with various motifs)  but also on kitchen towels, your explanation - while flowery - seems off.

Comment: It may '***seem***' off but it not necessarily '***is***' - who knooooows the intention of the creator in this special case. As I said: 'But of course one had to see the picture before making a serious guess...' - although it is rather 'fequent'... ;-)